# Set filter module

Tags: jquery, popup

There are a few bugs with my script that I can't figure out. When you click add, close the box with the black box on the upper right, and press add again quickly, the container popup box fades in then out again. I think it's because of the `setTimeout` but not sure why.

```
$('.add').stop().click(function() {
  if ($(this).stop().hasClass("isHere") ) {
  //nothing
  } else {

    $(".add").css({opacity: .8});
    $(".container").css({opacity: 0}).show('fast').animate({opacity: 1}, 200);
    $(this).addClass("isHere");

        $(".container").hover(
        function(){
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }, function()
        {
            timer = setTimeout(function(){
                $('.container form').reset();
                $(".container").animate({opacity: 0}).hide('fast');
                $(".add").removeClass("isHere").animate({opacity:.4}, 300);
            },380);
        });
  }
});
```

Working copy: http://jsfiddle.net/F7v9R/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `self.clearTimeout(timer)`.  I also like to specify that it is a window variable by prepending the variable name with window.  This helps newer devs that might see the code understand that it is associated with the window.

Comment: I read somewhere else about adding window.clearTimeout() but it and self didn't change anything....I'll keep that in mind for the future though. :)